# Extract Data from JSON php curl: json_decode not working

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following code:

```
<?php 

$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';
$url = '';

$data = array(
'grant_type'  => 'password',
    'username'    => '',
    'password'    => ''
);


$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Accept-Language: en_US'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $consumerKey.':'.$consumerSecret);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

It returns the sample following json result, but not the access token despite the json_decode. curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); does not return the token below. Thank you for helping me.

```
{"access_token":"ffdd8dfb-2013-32ee-bc3e-dc5689d6c8fb","refresh_token":"7bf1ddad-d696-3d83-a524-37dac002164a","scope":"default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

Comment: Why is there a `1` after the Json string? That will cause json_decode to not work I believe. EDIT: Without `1` it works fine. https://3v4l.org/Y0KKX

Comment: That is the response from `$access_token = $result->access_token;`

Comment: Hi @Andreas removed it but still unable to extract the access token.  
`$result = json_decode($result, true);
 $access_token = $result->access_token;`

Comment: What's this `}1`  after `json_decode` check `json_last_error` and `json_last_error_message`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it was the result of the `$access_token = $result->access_token;` I have updated the question without the line. Thanks

Comment: @Tai you are decoding to an associative array (the second parameter to json_decode set to true). Treat it as one :   `$result['access_token']`

Comment: @YvesLeBorg that one didn't also work. Returns the same results `{"access_token":"bc6f5997-221a-381d-9f5b-aa3bb380037d","refresh_token":"7bf1ddad-d696-3d83-a524-37dac002164a","scope":"default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buoyed by your answers - @Andreas and @YvesLeBorg, I redid the code and got what I want. I am putting this to help someone else. Thank you.

```
<?php 

$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';
$url = '';
$curl = curl_init($url);
$data = array(
    'grant_type'  => 'password',
    'username'    => '',
    'password'    => ''
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Accept-Language: en_US'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $consumerKey.':'.$consumerSecret);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    $access_token = $result->access_token;
echo $access_token;
    curl_close($curl);
```